# How to use index and value field of particle instance modifier

Tags: modifiers, particles

I have a particle instance modifier that actes upon a cylinder and uses a hair particle system.
If I try to type anything into the Index or value field to name them for use in a shader I get an error failed to find "

How can I assinge those attributes for later use?

I already tried to create vertex groups and color attributes but nothing showed up. I am using blender version 3.4

thanks for helping.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also having the same problem. The solution I found is selecting "Face Corner" on the "Domain" option and "Byte Color" on the "Data Type" option when creating a vertex color attribute. I don't know why, but for me just the attributes created this way, show up into the Index and Value field.
Hope this helps!

[image: color attribute options]